# Android 4.0 ice cream sandwich Dom Parser Null Pointer

Tags: android, dom

I have been using this code to parse xml till now. Its was working fine in previous version of android(till 2.3.3).

---

```
NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("course");         

Element entry;                              
Element title;

if(list != null && list.getLength() > 0){


     for(int i=0;i < list.getLength(); i++){

        entry = (Element)list.item(i);                              
        title = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("course").item(0);  

        biz_name_p = title.getAttribute("biz_name");

    }
}
```

---

I have Multiple tags with name "course" so i am taking it in a List. Inside loop im checking for elements course and extracting several string values from it.

It throws `NullPointerException` when i try to `getAttribute("biz_name")` or any other attributes.

This was working fine in previous version until ICS...

When i Replace "course" with primary tag in the list(which only repeats once in whole xml),
i am receiving the string value but only once... Did they change any thing in Dom parser ??

**EDIT**
following is the xml im trying to parse..

```
<golf> 
    <course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course"/>  
    <course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course1"/>
    <course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course2"/>
</golf>
```

Comment: Please also post your xml, or at least, some part of it related to question

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS : My bad ... following is the xml im trying to parse..
<golf>
<course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course"/>
<course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course1"/>
<course biz_name="Club Circle Golf Course2"/>

</golf>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why `getElementsByTagName` is called multiple times. So can you try this:

```
NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("course");         

Element entry;

if(list != null && list.getLength() > 0){

     for(int i=0;i < list.getLength(); i++){

        entry = (Element)list.item(i);
        biz_name_p = entry.getAttribute("biz_name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot.. this seems to work properly ... but i fail to understand why it was working fine in pervious android versions and not in ICS ?

Comment: That I don't understand neither. But I expect this to work also on previous versions.

Comment: yes this is working fine.. but i am having complication with xml which contains root tag with some attributes and few more tags inside it with their own attributes

I was creating nodelist for each tags till now , but in ICS i m getting 0 as nodelist length for the root tag(getting 1 previous android versions).. Here is the link for that xml

 http://api.amp.active.com/camping/campground/details?contractCode=CO&parkId=50032&api_key=2chxq68efd4azrpygt5hh2qu


M sorry for not formatting things properly i m new to stack overflow :)


Thnx for your super fast replies...

Comment: hey las_vegas i have created new question here is the link for that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066453/android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-parser-errors

Thnx for your support