# Android 4.0 ice cream sandwich Parser Errors

Tags: android, parsing, dom

I have made a application which reads information from an Api.

Link : http://api.amp.active.com/camping/campground/details?contractCode=CO&parkId=50032&api_key=2chxq68efd4azrpygt5hh2qu

Following is my code :

```
NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("detailDescription");

        Log.i("ZealDeveloper","I M In detail   "+list.getLength());             
        if(list != null && list.getLength() > 0){


            for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){

                entry = (Element) list.item(i);

                description = entry.getAttribute("description");
                drivingDirection = entry.getAttribute("drivingDirection");
                latitude=entry.getAttribute("latitude");
                longitude=entry.getAttribute("longitude");

            }               
        }

        NodeList list1 = element.getElementsByTagName("amenity");

        Log.i("ZealDeveloper","I M In 2   "+list1.getLength());

        if(list1 != null && list1.getLength() > 0){

            for(int i = 0; i < list1.getLength(); i++){
            entry = (Element) list1.item(i);

            nameAmenity = entry.getAttribute("name");

            listAmenity.add(nameAmenity);

            }               

            arrAmenity = listAmenity.toArray(new String[listAmenity.size()]);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for ( int i = 0; i < arrAmenity.length; i++ ){

                 builder.append(arrAmenity[i]+"\n");

            }
            txtAmenity.setText(builder);
    }
```

#

I am Getting `list.getLength()` as `0`(was getting `1` in pervious versions of android) , so the parser this condition. For amenity tag i m getting the desired list size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that "detailDescription" is already root of the document so probably `element` is the  tag you are seeking for. It doesn't have any children with the name "detailDescription" so `getElementsByTagName("detailDescription")` returns empty list. So change first half of your code as follows:

```
    Log.i("ZealDeveloper","I M In detail   " + element.getTagName()); 
    if(element.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("detailDescription")) {

            description = element.getAttribute("description");
            drivingDirection = element.getAttribute("drivingDirection");
            latitude = element.getAttribute("latitude");
            longitude = element.getAttribute("longitude");
    }  

    /* rest of your code...*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I switch from DOM to XPath. More [here](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2012/04/getelementsbytagname-returns-null-in.html)

Comment: I need to take nodeList as a Document how can I do that because after that I will use getElementByTagName.